# Visual Studio has lost reference to my project's classes

Tags: visual-studio

My visual studio project has 'lost' its references to all the classes within the project.

I'm now getting lots of error messages saying that "the type or namespace 'xxx' could not be found and I've lost all intellisense on those classes. It's fine with classes in external DLLs just not with classes within the project.

However the project builds OK.

Any ideas why this has happened and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the User Options File and then restarting Visual Studio fixed the problem.